# Using API to Add Waypoints to a Map

Tags: google-docs-api

I am having a website developed. My developer is using Google Maps API. I have a form where I am adding details to a database so that it shows a waypoint on a map. Right now I can add the post code and city and click on 'search' and it finds the address.... What I would rather do is simply enter the Business name and have the API pick it up and suggest which business I might be looking for (just like it does on Google Maps on my iphone). Is that at all possible? My Dev tells me that you cannot search for a venue using the name, instead it must be done by typing in the venue name manually and then only when I am typing the address can Google Maps API do its job and match to the address.

Surely this is not right? I'd love to hear your thoughts, thanks very much.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved using [Places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) in the Google Maps Platform. Unlike geocoding which is designed for postal addresses, Places allows for searching for establishments (either by name or by address). Places (autocomplete in particular) provides the best user experience, the only downside being that if you have a public-facing or automated component you need to be mindful of the pricing difference between the solutions.